# No muestra mi código en navegador y no logro encontrar el error!(js y vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente codigo. Y no logro encontrar el error. Estoy estudiando con un video de youtube. Pero como recién empiezo con vue, no tengo la capacidad suficiente para detectar que estoy haciendo mal que no me lo reconoce el navegador a la hora de hacerlo andar. Tengo algo mal puesto que halla comprendido mal?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

     <!--this div is with the action in scripp below-->
     <div id="appe">
         
    </div>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js">
         Vue.component("todo-item",{
             props: ['todo'],
             template: `<li> {{ todo.title }} </li>`
         })

         Vue.component("todo-list",{
              props: ['todos'],
              template: `
              <ul>
                <todo-item 
                v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
                :key="index"
                :todo="todo">
                </todo-item>
            </ul>
              `
         })
    const appe = new Vue({
    el: "#appe",
    data: {
        todos: [ //Array of job
            { title: "job 1", completed: false },
            { title: "job 2", completed: false },
            { title: "job 3", completed: false }
        ]
    },
    template: `
        <todo-list :todos="todos"></todo-list>
    `
    })
     </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El orden de tus scripts está mal

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Deberías llamar uno

```
<script>
   // codigo
</script>
```

Y en otro meter tu código, pero ya con Vue cargado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

     <!--this div is with the action in scripp below-->
     <div id="appe">
         
    </div>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
     <script>
              Vue.component("todo-item",{
             props: ['todo'],
             template: `<li> {{ todo.title }} </li>`
         })

         Vue.component("todo-list",{
              props: ['todos'],
              template: `
              <ul>
                <todo-item 
                v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
                :key="index"
                :todo="todo">
                </todo-item>
            </ul>
              `
         })
    const appe = new Vue({
    el: "#appe",
    data: {
        todos: [ //Array of job
            { title: "job 1", completed: false },
            { title: "job 2", completed: false },
            { title: "job 3", completed: false }
        ]
    },
    template: `
        <todo-list :todos="todos"></todo-list>
    `
    })
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Alberto. No sabes las horas que estuve buscándole la vuelta al código.